# Sortable Userlists best practice

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, sorting

I'm trying to do a webservice where multiple Users can be logged in at the same time. On the Nodejs server there is a unsorted array with all the users. And a Database with all users.

Every User can always see **every User online in a HTML Bootstrap Table**, with different columns for Username, Id, online since.... and there are also **lists for Groups that include online and offline Users.** The important part is, that the Table should be **updated like every 3-5 seconds**.

I want the Users to be able to sort the Online Users Table by clicking on the Tableheader of a Column. What is the best practice to do that?

I currently can only think of two different solutions, both don't seem perfect to me.

**1. Use Bootstrap sorting**

I save the information in which way the User wanted the list to be sorted.
Then I receive the unsorted Data and fill the Table with it, after which I will trigger a click on the header and sort the Table the same way again.

But if I do it this way I think the User will always notice that the Table is refilled and then sorted againm if done every 3-5 Seconds.

**2. Keep sorted lists on the Server**

Keep all the different sorted lists of the Users on my Server at all Time and let the server sort them new every 3-5 Seconds.
Then when the client requests it, send the sorted list he currently wants to the client and fill the Table HTML.

But this way I think it would use quite some resources from my server, because it also has to sort some mixed online/offline Users for groups which would be many different tables I had to constantly save and reorder on my server.

**Are there any better ways to achieve many sortable Userlists for the clientside?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing about the UI is to reduce flicker and any kind of lag.  First off try testing sorting on the user end before the data is displayed in the table.  You don't want to trigger the click events because that might make a flicker effect where the data comes in, is displayed, sorted, then displayed again.  If for some reason the sorting is taking too long this could result in lag or choppiness on the ui so test it out and see how it feels.  I would only look to the server side if the client side isn't performing well.  Check your CPU and RAM to see how best to handle that. The sorting on the fly might be doable with your setup or keeping it in RAM may be an option if you have some to spare.

Serverside stored in a site-wide or thread-engine variable in ram.  If you can get away with it the thread-engine variable will be the fastest option but the cost would be SORTEDDATA_BYTES * WEB_THREADS.

```
Array.prototype.keySort = function(k, descending) {
  var z = descending === true ? -1 : 1;
  this.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[k] > b[k] ? 1*z : a[k] < b[k] ? -1*z : 0;
  });
  return this;
};

var sortedJSON = {
  UsernameAsc: JSON.stringify(data.keySort("Username")),
  UsernameDesc: JSON.stringify(data.keySort("Username", true)),
  IdAsc: JSON.stringify(data.keySort("Id")),
  IdDesc: JSON.stringify(data.keySort("Id", true))
};
```